# How to throw validation message, when there is some change in the edit item using angular8

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am using reactive forms formArray to add the section of data on click of add, and on click of edit, after editing i have used delete and save button to save to the table.
So basically one operation at a time must be done. So, when i click on edit, Add New button will be disabled and after saving the data, i am enabling the Add button. So, now if i have made changes in the item by using edit, and click to delete or take up a new item to edit, then alert message must throw up saying, you want to delete changes made so far. I am trying to implement but it works only for the first time and from next time it start showing alert message for every click on edit icon. 
Can anyone help me out to make it work.

DEMO: 
[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-opgbqx?file=src/app/user-table/user-table.component.ts)

HTML of Table to where i am pushing data and displaying what i have added and what items i am getting from backend.

```
<table class="table table-hover accordion-table"
        *ngIf="agentDetailsList?.w9Info || temporaryControls.length != 0">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col" *ngFor="let field of w9ListDetails"> {{field.displayName}}
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="width75">Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let w9 of agentDetailsList?.w9Info ? agentDetailsList.w9Info : temporaryControls ">
            <td *ngFor="let field of w9ListDetails">
              {{w9[field.param]}}
            </td>
            <td class="width75">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-table {{isReadOnly ? 'link-disabled' : ''}}"
                title="View" (click)="downLoadFiles(w9)"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-table ml-1 {{isReadOnly ? 'link-disabled' : ''}}"
                title="Edit" (click)="editw9(w9, 'editMode')"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

HTML of formArray:

```
<div class="card-body" *ngIf="agentW9InfoForm" [formGroup]='agentW9InfoForm'>
        <form formArrayName="w9Info" *ngFor="let item of agentW9InfoForm.controls.w9Info?.controls; let i = index;">
          <div class="border rounded p-3 position-relative" [formGroupName]="i">
            <button class="btn btn-link btn-close position-absolute" (click)="deleteW9Details(i,item)"
              [class.disabled]="isReadOnly"><i class="fas fa-times fa-lg"></i></button>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="">Tax ID Number <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control {{w9ReadOnly ? 'link-disabled' : ''}}"
                    placeholder="Tax ID Number" name="taxId" formControlName="taxId" maxlength="50"
                    autocomplete="new-tx" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && item.controls.taxId.errors }"
                    allowNumberOnly>
                  <div *ngIf="submitted && item.controls.taxId.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="item.hasError('required', 'taxId')">Tax Id is required</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="">Signature Date <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control {{w9ReadOnly ? 'link-disabled' : ''}}" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"
                    name="signatureDate" formControlName="signatureDate"
                    [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && item.controls.signatureDate.errors }">
                  <div *ngIf="submitted && item.controls.signatureDate.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="item.controls.signatureDate.errors.required">Signature Date is required</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-6">
                <div class="form-group ">
                  <label for="">Business Type <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                  <select class="custom-select {{w9ReadOnly ? 'link-disabled' : ''}}" name="businessType"
                    formControlName="businessType"
                    [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && item.controls.businessType.errors }">
                    <option value=''>Select Business Type </option>
                    <option *ngFor="let businessType of detailsSelectDropDown?.W9BusinessType"
                      [value]='businessType.id'>
                      {{businessType.value}}</option>
                  </select>
                  <div *ngIf="submitted && item.controls.businessType.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="item.controls.businessType.errors.required">Business Type is required</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="row" *ngIf="!hideUpload">
              <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group" >
                  <label for="">Upload File</label>
                  <div class="form-control" (click)="fileInput.click()" appDragDrop
                    (onFileDropped)="uploadFile($event,item.controls)">
                    <input hidden type="file" #fileInput (change)="uploadFile($event,item.controls)"
                      class="custom-file-input" id="uploadFile" formControlName="fileName">
                      <span>{{ item.controls.fileName.value?.slice(12) }}</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-6">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary mt-4" id="" (click)="upload()">Upload</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end align-items-end">
                <button class="btn btn-primary delbtn" (click)="saveW9Details(item.controls,i)"
                  [class.disabled]="isReadOnly">
                  Save
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        <div class="row mt-3">
          <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end align-items-end">
            <div class="form-group {{addButtonDisable ? 'link-disabled' : ''}}">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary {{isReadOnly ? 'link-disabled' : ''}}"
                (click)="addW9Details()"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add New</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

TS:

```
deleteW9Details(i) {
      let error = !this.getFormData.invalid && this.getFormData.dirty
    if(!error == true) {
      this.getFormData.removeAt(i);

    } else {
      alert('are you sure to delete')

    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<button class="col-2 pull-left m-b10 m-t10 delbtn" (click)="deleteW9Details(i)"
          [class.disabled]="isReadOnly">
          Delete
        </button>
         <button class="col-2 pull-left m-b10 m-t10 delbtn" (click)="saveW9Details(item.controls)"
          [class.disabled]="isReadOnly">
          Save
        </button>
```

TS of FormArray:

```
  private w9InfoFormInit() {
    if (!this.groupCode && !this.agentCode) {
      // Add
      this.agentW9InfoForm = this.FB.group({
        w9Info: this.FB.array([this.createW9Information()])
      })
    } else {
      //edit
        this.agentW9InfoForm = this.FB.group({
               w9Info:this.FB.array([])
             })
   }
    if (this.mode == 1) {
      this.agentW9InfoForm.disable()
      this.isReadOnly = true;
    }
  }

  editw9InfoDetails(w9,mode) {
    let modes = mode
    if("editMode" ) {
      this.hideUpload = true;
      this.saveUpload = false
    } else {
     this.hideUpload = false;
     this.saveUpload =true
    }
    this.addButtonDisable = true;
    const control = <FormArray>this.agentW9InfoForm.get('w9Info');
    control.controls = []; 
    let info = [];
    info.push(w9)
    for (const emp of info) {
     const grp = this.FB.group({
       taxId: [emp.taxId, Validators.required],
       signatureDate: [emp.signatureDate, [Validators.required]],
       businessType: [emp.businessType, [Validators.required]],
       fileName:[emp.fileName],
       agentW9id:[emp.agentW9id],
       originalFileName: [emp.originalFileName],
       agentCode:[emp.agentCode],
       id:[emp.id]
     });
     control.push(grp);
   }
  }
  editw9(w9,mode) {
    let error = !this.w9InfoDetails.invalid && this.w9InfoDetails.dirty
    if(error != true) {
      this.editw9InfoDetails(w9,mode)

    } else {
      this.notificationService.activate("Validation Message", "Are you sure to delete changes? ", "Yes").then(responseOK => {
        if (responseOK) {
        this.editw9InfoDetails(w9,mode)

        } 
      });
    }

  }
```

Craeting of form Array along with delete and edit of the row items,

```
 public addW9Details() {
    this.hideUpload = false;
    this.w9ReadOnly = false;
    if(this.agentDetailsList && this.agentDetailsList.w9Info) {
      this.saveUpload = false;
    } else {
      this.saveUpload = true;
    }
    const control = <FormArray>this.agentW9InfoForm.get('w9Info');
    if(this.agentDetailsList && this.agentDetailsList.w9Info) {
      control.controls = []; 
    } 
    control.push(this.createW9Information());
    this.addButtonDisable = true;

  }

  public deleteW9Details(i,item) {
    let error = !this.w9InfoDetails.invalid && this.w9InfoDetails.dirty
    if(!error == true) {
      this.w9InfoDetails.removeAt(i);
      this.addButtonDisable = false
    } else {
      this.notificationService.activate("Validation Message", "Are you sure to delete changes? ", "Yes").then(responseOK => {
        if (responseOK) {
          this.w9InfoDetails.removeAt(i);
          this.addButtonDisable = false
        } 
      });
    }

  }

  public preventW9DetailsEmpty() {
    if (!this.w9InfoDetails.length) {
      let group = this.createW9Information();
      group.reset();
      this.agentW9InfoForm.setControl('w9Info', this.FB.array([group]));
    }
  }

  public get w9InfoDetails(): FormArray {
    return <FormArray>this.agentW9InfoForm.controls['w9Info'];
  }

  private createW9Information() {
    return this.FB.group({
      taxId: [null, Validators.required],
      signatureDate: [null, Validators.required],
      businessType: [null, Validators.required],
      originalFileName: [''],
      agentW9id:0,
      fileName: [''],
      agentCode:parseInt(this.agentbasicInfoForm.controls['agentCode'].value),
      id:''
    });
  }
```

Saving of newly added row item/save of edit item to grid both part code contains here:

```
  saveW9Details(item, num) {

      if(this.w9InfoDetails.invalid) {
        this.notificationService.activate("Validation Message", "Please fill Tax Id Number,Signature Date, Business Type", "OK", false).then(responseOK => {
          if (responseOK) {

          }
        });
      } else {
        this.addButtonDisable = false;
        if(this.agentDetailsList && this.agentDetailsList.w9Info) {
          if(item.agentW9id.value) {
            for(var i=0;i<this.agentDetailsList.w9Info.length;i++){
              let itembusinessName = this.detailsSelectDropDown.W9BusinessType.filter(x => x.id === parseInt(item.businessType.value));
              if(this.agentDetailsList.w9Info[i].agentW9id===item.agentW9id.value){
                this.agentDetailsList.w9Info[i].taxId=item.taxId.value;
                this.agentDetailsList.w9Info[i].businessType=item.businessType.value;
                this.agentDetailsList.w9Info[i].signatureDate=item.signatureDate.value;
                this.agentDetailsList.w9Info[i].agentW9id = item.agentW9id.value;
                this.agentDetailsList.w9Info[i].businessName = itembusinessName[0].value;
                this.agentDetailsList.w9Info[i].id = itembusinessName[0].id;
                // updated=true;
                this.temporaryControls.push(this.agentDetailsList.w9Info[i])
              }
           }
          }  
          else {
            let itembusinessName = this.detailsSelectDropDown.W9BusinessType.filter(x => x.id === parseInt(item.businessType.value));
            console.log(itembusinessName,"business")

            let temp={
              taxId:item.taxId.value,
              signatureDate:item.signatureDate.value,
              businessType: item.businessType.value,
              agentW9id:item.agentW9id.value,
              businessName: itembusinessName[0].value,
             originalFileName:item.fileName.value?item.fileName.value.slice(12):'',
             id: this.temporaryControls.length
            }
            if(this.agentDetailsList&& this.agentDetailsList.w9Info) {
              this.agentDetailsList.w9Info.push(temp);
              this.temporaryControls.push(temp)
            } 
            console.log(this.temporaryControls,"dssdf")
          }
        } 


        else {
          let itembusinessName = this.detailsSelectDropDown.W9BusinessType.filter(x => x.id === parseInt(item.businessType.value));
            console.log(itembusinessName,"business")
            let temp={
              taxId:item.taxId.value,
              signatureDate:item.signatureDate.value,
              businessType: item.businessType.value,
              agentW9id:item.agentW9id.value,
              businessName: itembusinessName[0].value,
             originalFileName:item.fileName.value?item.fileName.value.slice(12):'',
             id: this.temporaryControls.length

            };
            console.log(temp,"dsfdsg")
            this.temporaryControls.push(temp)
        }

        console.log(this.temporaryControls,"dssdf")
       this.w9InfoDetails.removeAt(item);
       console.log(this.temporaryControls,"temp")
      }
        }
```

Comment: What errors is it throwing and what is throwing them? What is `i` in `deleteW9Details(i)`? Is that an index? Does it get updated accurately? The code in your post is incomplete and can't be run as-is to show the issue.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, thanks for response, i have kept the working demo, please run it once. I have given all my codes over there. Here alert message comes for the first time, when i try to edit an item and delete, but after that when i click on edit button, the alert message pops up before it opens the section controls

Comment: ya if i click on particular item in a row, while editing, it clears the edited items, and yes i is the index

Comment: I can't access the external site. The question itself should contain the minimum amount of code to show a viable working example of the issue at hand. External sites should not be relied upon because they can get out of date, change, or disappear, rendering the question worthless.

Comment: you just have to keep a boolean field just check if there is form in edit mode

Comment: Can you explain your requirement?

Comment: here, when i click on edit button, and section opens, if i change anything like taxid or signature date or businesstype and try to click on other edit button on the other row, it must throw validation error message asking you want to delete changes, incase if i have not done any changes for the one which i had clicked on edit button then alert shouldnt come

Comment: I have checked the stackblitz have lot of code if it's possible can you  re create stackblitz>

Comment: @Chellappanவ, as you asked i have recreated stackblitz, can you please have a look https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-yhpklb?file=src/app/user-table/user-table.component.ts

Comment: I will update today sorry about delay

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207373/discussion-between-chellappan--and-bhrungarajni).

Comment: @Chellappanவ any updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On edit method editw9(), you are getting message 'are you sure to delete', because after edit and save for the first time, "error" is always getting set to true from next edit click onwards, it is because this.getFormData.dirty is returning true.

```
let error = !this.getFormData.invalid && this.getFormData.dirty
```

On save method call `this.getFormData.markAsPristine();` as last line, which will reset dirty flag of the form

Comment: Any idea about this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60146919/how-to-edit-or-add-one-row-at-a-time-using-reactive-forms-in-angular8