# Date in formControlName not taking the value using reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am using reactive forms, in this if i click on date from the bootstrap calendar, the value is coming as empty, but if i change the selected date from the formControl input, then that value has been taken. I am not getting where i am going wrong.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-kgheve?file=src/app/user-table/user-table.component.html)

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Premium Commitment Date</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" formControlName="premiumCommDate"
                  name="premiumCommDate"></div>
```

Ts:

```
 $('.onlyDate').datetimepicker({
        format: 'L'
      });

this.agentbasicInfoForm = this.FB.group({
        premiumCommDate: [''],
})
```

Comment: Don't use Jquery with angular, check this for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53534894/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-use-jquery-in-angular

Comment: Hi thanks for response, but based on my requirement that was the only way I found with very limited time, can you please help me to solve it

Comment: There are lot of angular based date picker available ,can't you use that?

Comment: here, i need date time along with Am/pm, and in this project other plugins cannot be used. that is the main problem i had

Comment: premiumCommDate cannot be found in given demo project

Comment: sorry, il change code, here for more things i have added this date calendar this, can you please check for signature date

Comment: in signature date same kind has been used, il update code.

Comment: is that signature date fine, or shall i give with premiumCommDate?

Comment: Stackblitz example does not have any jquery code, In which place are you getting date picker value?

Comment: in stackblitz i have updated jquery code as well, sorry i had forgot to fork it, now everything is available there.

Comment: @Chellappanவ, is my demo clear, shall i change anything?

Comment: Since you using jquert datepicker you have to use jqueryDate picker event to get date

Comment: Like how?? Any example can you show please

Comment: @Chellappanவ, have you got time to have a look?

Comment: I did not get time, I will check. When I am free!

Comment: yes sure, please let me know when you get free time, i am badly struck here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207104/discussion-between-bhrungarajni-and-chellappan-).

Comment: @Chellappanவ, any idea how to bind date for the ngModel?

Comment: @Chellappanவ i have added stackblitz code, https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-ia2p6q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser-table%2Fuser-table.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since using Jquery, you have to listen datepickerchange event to get datepicker value, then set the reactive form value manullay using setValue or patchValue.

**Try this:**

```
date(event,i) {
   $('.onlyDateTime').datetimepicker();
      $('.onlyDate').datetimepicker({
        format: 'L'
      });
   $('.onlyDate').datetimepicker(
    { format: 'L' }).on('dp.change', (e)=>{
      const date = e.date.format('L');
      this.getFormData.at(i).get('signatureDate').setValue(date,{emitEvent:false});
      });
  }
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-dcphwl)

Comment: any idea about my other question of phone number validators

Comment: when you get free time, can you please help me in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59992013/how-to-throw-validation-message-when-there-is-some-change-in-the-edit-item-usin?

Comment: have you got time to go through my question?

Comment: Will check and let you know!

Comment: Hi, from this answer, can you please help me out to bind values for the array of objects which dont have formControl name

Comment: for date i have only ngModel, and the date value is taking if i manually change the date, but not taking the date from the calender, i tried with ngModelChange also but its not working

Comment: Hi Bro @Bhrungarajni Can you share stackblitz. If it's not complicated i will give immediately else it will take some time

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-ia2p6q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser-table%2Fuser-table.component.html

Comment: Try this: dateRestriction(event,restriction) {
       $('.onlyDateTime').datetimepicker();
      $('.onlyDate').datetimepicker({
        format: 'L'
      });
   $('.onlyDateTime').datetimepicker(
    ).on('dp.change', (e)=>{
      const date = e.date;
      console.log(e.date.format('L'));
        this.Restrictions[restriction].datetime = e.date.format('L')
      });
  }

Comment: hi, here you are considering only date format, but i need both daate and time

Comment: You have to check the JQuery date picker documentation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60088398/how-to-bind-value-to-the-array-of-object-based-on-date-selection-in-angular8

Comment: we shall talk there, i am getting date time with full length in other 2 dateTime values