# How to bind value to the array of object based on date selection in angular8

Tags: angular, ngmodel

i have array of objects, here if the date is picked from the datetime calender, the value is not binding to that object, but if i change the date manually then it works, but if i select from calendar then the value is nit binding. I have tried with (change) and (ngModelChange), but both didnt work.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-6 
            *ngFor="let restrictValue of Restrictions;let i = index">

            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control onlyDateTime" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM AM/PM"
                [disabled]="!restrictValue.boolValue" [(ngModel)]="restrictValue.datetime" (change)="dateRestriction($event,restrictValue)" (click)="dateRestriction($event, i)"
                [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" >
            </div>
          </div>
```

TS:

```
dateRestriction(event,restriction) {
       $('.onlyDateTime').datetimepicker();
      $('.onlyDate').datetimepicker({
        format: 'L'
      });
   $('.onlyDateTime').datetimepicker(
    ).on('dp.change', (e)=>{
      const date = e.date;

      });
  }
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-ia2p6q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser-table%2Fuser-table.component.html)

Comment: @Chellappan from this demo, i should not enable the dates before present day, can that be handled?

Comment: @Chellappan i need your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
dateRestriction(event, restriction) {
    $(".onlyDateTime").datetimepicker();
    $(".onlyDate").datetimepicker({ format: "L" });
    $(".onlyDateTime")
      .datetimepicker()
      .on("dp.change", e => {
        const date = e.date;
        this.Restrictions[restriction].datetime = date.format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss A");
      });
  }
```

Comment: here am/pm fomat is also required as per requirement

Comment: how about that formArray question, can we solve that by today?

Comment: I don't know I will check for sure~!

Comment: yes please, if that is solved, then i can proceed with my other things, sorry but thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60089673/angular-8-deployment-issue-not-opening-the-router-when-passed-via-window-open-in

Comment: i have multiple date fields but the date is taking only to the last selected field

Comment: how can that be handled?

Comment: Can you share your question?

Comment: Yes i will create and share

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60150277/how-to-bind-the-date-values-to-its-particular-field-in-angular8

Comment: this is my question

Comment: if you get time please have a look at my question

Comment: from this demo, i should not enable the dates before present day, can that be handled?