# How to bind the date values to its particular field in angular8

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

i am using bootstrap date picker, in which if i select date for one field, the same date is replicating to the other fields as well. I want the selected date to be binded to the formcontrolName instead of taking only one value at a time.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rfpmmx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

TS:

```
focusEffectivDate(name) {
      $('.onlyDate').datetimepicker(
        { format: 'L' }).on('dp.change', (e) => {
          const date = e.date.format('L');
          if(name == 'effectiveDate') {
            this.eoInfoForm.get('effectiveDate').setValue(date, { emitEvent: false });
          } else if(name == 'expirationDate') {
            this.eoInfoForm.get('expirationDate').setValue(date, { emitEvent: false });
          } else {
            this.eoInfoForm.get('updateReceivedDate').setValue(date, { emitEvent: false });
          }

        });
  }
```

Comment: 1. Don't use jQuery with Angular. 2. I would recommend using the ng-bootstrap library

Comment: ng-bootstrap have an implementation of datepicker: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview

Comment: as per my requirement this bootstrap with jquery must be used, only this calendar is satisfying my need so i have used it and no plugins not used

Comment: Never use jQuery with angular (if it's only way then use it), angular is providing everything use that it will easy to implement

Comment: can anyone help me with this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60146919/how-to-edit-or-add-one-row-at-a-time-using-reactive-forms-in-angular8

Comment: I have kind of got it working for you (albeit buggy - datepicker only shows on second click - I'm happy to demonstrate possibility, not get it production ready), but I feel really dirty doing this. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ztfvav. I moved the datepicker binding into main.js. But my main advice on this - this does not belong in Angular. Or at least if you **must** do it this way, then at least use as much Angular as possible (e.g. *ngIf, (click) event handler on button).

Comment: Thanks for response, but it is working as same way it was working in my demo link, i hope you might have not forked it

Comment: @kurl Hamilton thanks for your suggestion but in my worst case I tried it, but from next time I avoid using jquery, and the same code I had put up in main.js but that didn’t work for me so I brought to component itself, any help to bind values to particular fields instead of duplication of same value

Comment: @KurtHamilton any idea about this?

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: here, if i give date for one field, and i go to second field and select date, that same date is taking to the previous one also

Comment: @Bhrungarajni Honestly, my advice is to find a datepicker that works with Angular. You're going to need a strong understanding of both Angular and jQuery to get this to work, and you're not going to get someone here to write a working Angular / jQuery datepicker integration.

Comment: @Chellappanவ is it possible to add disabled for start and end date from this datepicker?

Comment: have you tried disable attribute?

Comment: [disabled] like this for new date()?

Comment: @Chellappanவ from this demo, i should not enable the dates before present day, can that be handled? https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-eg89kb?file=src/app/user-table/user-table.component.ts

Comment: @Chellappanவ have you got time to go through my question?

Comment: No bro, I have lot of work!, Will check when i am free

Comment: @Chellappanவ sure bro when you get free time, please dont forget to have a look, thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I tried with disabled dates and using moment but nothing worked bro

Comment: @Chellappanவ in this demo answer, i am not able bind the new dates to the input fields, it takes same value to all the fields

Comment: Hai bro i am out of station, wil try your answer tom or day after tomorrow

Comment: @Chellappanவ thats ok not a problem,

Comment: @Chellappanவ this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60276987/how-to-give-different-dates-for-array-of-objects-using-angular8?noredirect=1#comment106621484_60276987

Comment: @Chellappanவ hi bro got sometime to go through my issue?

Comment: @Chellappanவ when you get time please have a look at this question, very hogh priority i have https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60276987/how-to-give-different-dates-for-array-of-objects-using-angular8?noredirect=1#comment106621484_60276987

Comment: @Chellappanவ please need your help in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62151803/how-to-make-arrow-keys-work-when-we-set-mindate-based-on-the-selection-of-anothe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you calling datepicker's onChange function inside focusEffectivDate, multiple instances of onchange function are created(on every time input field blur). So try to move your date picker onChange event to AfterviewInit. Then store that value in some property and use that value to set reactive form value.

**component.ts**

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
   $('.onlyDate').datetimepicker(
        { format: 'L' }).on('dp.change', (e) => {
          const date = e.date.format('L');
          console.log(date);
         this.date = date;

    });
}

focusEffectivDate(name) {
     if(name == 'effectiveDate') {
            this.eoInfoForm.get('effectiveDate').setValue(this.date, { emitEvent: false });
          } else if(name == 'expirationDate') {
            this.eoInfoForm.get('expirationDate').setValue(this.date, { emitEvent: false });
          } else {
            this.eoInfoForm.get('updateReceivedDate').setValue(this.date, { emitEvent: false });
     }
}
```

[Forked Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mog8cb)