# How to give different dates for array of objects using angular8

Tags: javascript, angular

I have used bootstarp 4 datetimepicker in angular8 application. here i am getting the latest date in all 3 fields, but i have to get the date which i give to that particular field. i have used ngModel, is that issue based on that?

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-xadekv?file=src/app/user-table/user-table.component.html)

TS:

```
dateRestriction(event, restriction) {
    $(".onlyDateTime").datetimepicker();
    $(".onlyDate").datetimepicker({ format: "L" });
    $(".onlyDateTime")
      .datetimepicker()
      .on("dp.change", e => {
        const date = e.date;
        console.log(e.date.format("L"));
        this.Restrictions[restriction].datetime = e.date.format("L");
      });
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-6 {{isReadOnly ? 'link-disabled' : ''}}"
            *ngFor="let restrictValue of Restrictions;let i = index">
            <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
              <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="{{restrictValue.id}}"
                [checked]="restrictValue.boolValue" (change)="restrictValue.boolValue = $event.target.checked"
                >
              <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{restrictValue.id}}">{{restrictValue.label}}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control onlyDateTime" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM AM/PM"
                [disabled]="!restrictValue.boolValue" [(ngModel)]="restrictValue.datetime" (change)="dateRestriction($event,restrictValue)" (click)="dateRestriction($event, i)"
                [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" >
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: What's the issue? Why have you disabled the inputs in the demo? Why are you using jQuery with Angular?

Comment: based on checkbox checked, that particular fields will be enabled, then we can add date there, if disabled, date cant be entered, and as per requirement i got this jquery only which has both datetime picker

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the disabled check boxes there. Still, try to use an alternative that doesn't use jQuery if you can. There are many native Angular datepickers to choose from.

Comment: but here except bootstrap4, i shouldnt use any other plugins also, i hope issue is with the ngModel i have i used but not getting how to sollve it

Comment: move this.Restrictions[i].datetime = dat;  line of code inside dp.onChange event call back

Comment: Done that as well but didn’t work, because that i value is taking previous index value

Comment: Inside event it is not taking the updated index value, after coming out of 2nd click index that value getting binded

Comment: @Chellappanவ, could you please have a look at this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60360555/how-to-bind-array-of-ojects-to-formgroup-and-formarray-using-angular8

Comment: as far as i know u r very good at formarray and reactive forms, so need help in binding the array of objects to formArray

Comment: this is demo link, i made it work without using reactive forms, same way i want this to work in that question demo link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lh5vzl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I need your sometime, if you spend a little time on this, it won’t be tricky for you to solve, please if possible have a look and give me helping hand

Comment: @Chellappanவ Thanks for your constant support, but can you please tell how can i set the other datepicker for one year of the selected date

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60580834/how-to-set-the-calendar-to-one-year-from-the-selected-date-using-angular8-with-b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you using  Jquery date picker change event for datetimepicker. It's getting called before click event of date picker.

**Try this**

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
     $(".onlyDate").datetimepicker({ format: "L" });
      let dat = null;
       $(".onlyDate")
      .datetimepicker()
      .on("dp.hide", e => {
        const date = e.date;
         let dat = e.date.format("L");
        this.Restrictions[this.selectedIndex].datetime = dat;
      });
   }

  dateRestriction( i) {
    this.selectedIndex = i;
  }
```

[Forked Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-ds9qqo)

Comment: thanks fr response but date calendar is not opening

Comment: Jquery is not loading properly in stackblitz change something in your code and try

Comment: i did small change, in the second jquery i added onlyDateTime and it worked

Comment: i tried like this and it worked, thanks a lot https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-4bgun3?file=src/app/user-table/user-table.component.ts

Comment: please have a look at this, when you get time, please and thank you soo much bro, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60321749/is-there-a-way-to-detect-the-valuechanges-for-formarray-which-has-been-dynamical?noredirect=1#comment106704265_60321749