# Edit newly added row and update the changes to that row instead of creating new item using formArray reactive forms in angular8

Tags: angular, forms, reactive, angular-reactive-forms

i have formArray, if i create new item and update that particular item, instead of getting updated it is getting added newly, and it must send to final save only the last updated values instead of creating new items for every edit of newly added item.

DEMO:
[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-rdrazg?file=src/app/user-table/user-table.component.ts)

TS:

```
 saveW9Details(item) {
this.addButtonDisable = false;
        if(this.employee ) {
          if(item.agentW9id.value) {
            for(var i=0;i<this.employee.length;i++){
              if(this.employee[i].agentW9id===item.agentW9id.value){
                this.employee[i].taxId=item.taxId.value;
                this.employee[i].businessType=item.businessType.value;
                this.employee[i].signatureDate=item.signatureDate.value;
                this.employee[i].agentW9id = item.agentW9id.value;
                // updated=true;
                this.temporaryControls.push(this.employee[i]);
                this.getFormData.removeAt(i)
              }
           }
          } else {

            var temp={
              taxId:item.taxId.value,
              signatureDate:item.signatureDate.value,
              businessType: item.businessType.value,
              agentW9id:item.agentW9id.value,
             originalFileName:item.fileName.value?item.fileName.value.slice(12):''
            }
            if(this.employee) {
              this.employee.push(temp);
              this.temporaryControls.push(temp)
            } 
      //  this.getFormData.removeAt(item)
          }
        } else {
         console.log(item,"dsds")

            let temp={
              taxId:item.taxId.value,
              signatureDate:item.signatureDate.value,
              businessType: item.businessType.value,
              agentW9id:item.agentW9id.value,
              businessName: item.businessName[0].value,
             originalFileName:item.fileName.value?item.fileName.value.slice(12):''
            };
            this.temporaryControls.push(temp)
        }

       this.getFormData.removeAt(item);


        }
```

Can anyone help me to solve this, i am not getting where i am going wrong.

Comment: When you add / update you are checking item.agentW9id.value so if you don't input anything there you are inserting new row according to your

Comment: yes, i was able to solve this, thanks for response mustafa

Comment: any idea about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59992013/how-to-throw-validation-message-when-there-is-some-change-in-the-edit-item-usin?noredirect=1#comment106191374_59992013